# Calculate amount from transactions/events

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Don't know if this is in the correct category but I'm trying to calculate amounts in sql.
This what I have:

One table with transactions. That's it basically. Every transaction represents an "deposit" or "withdrawal" of a product from a shelf. There's no data of the amount of products in the shelf and now I would like to calculate the amount of products in all shelfs during the day. Every day.

Table:

```
Transaction Datetime, Source, Destination, Product ID, Product Group
2019-02-01 08:01:00, Person1, Shelf1, 1234, 1
2019-02-01 10:01:00, Shelf1, Person1, 1234, 1
2019-02-01 08:03:00, Person2, Shelf1, 5678, 1
...
```

Desired table:

```
Hour, Date, Shelf, Product Group, Amount
8, 2019-02-01, Shelf1, 1, 5
9, 2019-02-01, Shelf1, 1, 10
10, 2019-02-01, Shelf1, 1, 10
```

Any ideas how to do this? Any suggestion would be appreciated

Br
Cris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `datetime_trunc()` and put the hour in the same column as the date.

But the fundamental idea is to "switch" the rows so shelves are always the source and add an indicator for the amount (negative for going in the other direction).

You can use a cumulative sum to get the net amount at the end of each hour.  Or just use plan aggregation to get the changes during the hour.

```
select datetime_trunc(transaction_datetime, hour) date yyyymmddhh,
       Shelf, Product_Group,
       sum(inc) as changes_this_hour,
       sum(sum(inc)) over (partition by shelf,  product_id, product_group order by min(transaction_datetime)) as net_amount
from ((select transaction_datetime,
              source, destination, product_id, product_group,
              1 as inc
       from t
       where source like 'Shelf%'
      )
      union all
      (select transaction_datetime,
              destination, source,  product_id, product_group,
              -1 as inc
       from t
       where destination like 'Shelf%'
      )
     ) t
group by yyyymmddhh, Shelf,  product_id, Product_Group
order by Shelf, Product_Group;
```

Comment: Thanks! This works fine! But, I have rows only for the hours when I got any changes. I need the

Comment: Thanks Gordon! This works perfect! Now I have rows only for the hours when I got any changes. I need one row per hour even if changes don't happen because I need the amount per hour. If I join a table with one row per hour per date where the "yyyymmddhh" is equal and greater than and less than the datetime in the "hour" table I should get amount per hour....

Answer (score 1):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

The idea is to first collect all

- locations of product (Source and Destination)
- all product groups
- and finally all hours/days to create report for

Then `CROSS JOIN` all three above and `LEFT JOIN` with main data ON hour, day, location and product_group while calculating amount based on what location represents - Source or Destination.

Next, all amounts are grouped within same hour/day and obviously location and Product_Group
And finally, analytic function is applied to calculate cumulative amounts

Final code with sampled data is below

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT DATETIME '2019-02-01 08:01:00' Transaction_Datetime, 'Person1' Source, 'Shelf1' Destination, 1234 Product_ID, 1 Product_Group UNION ALL
  SELECT '2019-02-01 10:01:00', 'Shelf1', 'Person1', 1234, 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT '2019-02-01 08:03:00', 'Person2', 'Shelf1', 5678, 1 
), hours AS (
  SELECT EXTRACT(HOUR FROM hour) hour, DATE(hour) day
  FROM (
    SELECT 
      MIN(TIMESTAMP(Transaction_Datetime)) min_ts,
      MAX(TIMESTAMP(Transaction_Datetime)) max_ts
    FROM `project.dataset.table`
  ), UNNEST(GENERATE_TIMESTAMP_ARRAY(
    TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(min_ts, HOUR),
    TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(max_ts, HOUR),
    INTERVAL 1 HOUR)) hour
), locations AS (
  SELECT Source AS location FROM `project.dataset.table`
  UNION DISTINCT 
  SELECT Destination FROM `project.dataset.table`
), product_groups AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT Product_Group FROM `project.dataset.table`
), temp AS (
  SELECT 
    EXTRACT(HOUR FROM Transaction_Datetime) hour,
    DATE(Transaction_Datetime) day,
    Source, Destination, Product_ID, Product_Group
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
)
SELECT hour, day, location, product_group,
  SUM(delta) OVER(PARTITION BY location, product_group ORDER BY hour, day) amount
FROM (
  SELECT 
    hours.hour, hours.day, location, product_groups.product_group,
    SUM(CASE location 
      WHEN Source THEN -1
      WHEN Destination THEN 1
      ELSE 0
    END) delta 
  FROM locations, hours, product_groups
  LEFT JOIN temp t
  ON t.hour = hours.hour
  AND t.day = hours.day
  AND t.product_group = product_groups.product_group
  AND location IN (Source, Destination)
  GROUP BY hours.hour, hours.day, location, Product_Group
)
WHERE LOWER(location) LIKE 'shelf%' 
-- ORDER BY hour, day, location
```

with result

```
Row hour    day         location    product_group   amount   
1   8       2019-02-01  Shelf1      1       2    
2   9       2019-02-01  Shelf1      1       2    
3   10      2019-02-01  Shelf1      1       1
```

Note: it is not exactly clear from your question how to distinguish `Shelf` from `Person` - so `LOWER(location) LIKE 'shelf%'` is used. You can adjust this to use whatever logic you have for this
If you will remove that line  - you will get amount of not only for shelves  - but also balance of product in each person's "hand"

To test with your table - run below - don't forget to replace `project.dataset.table` with your full table reference

```
#standardSQL
WITH hours AS (
  SELECT EXTRACT(HOUR FROM hour) hour, DATE(hour) day
  FROM (
    SELECT 
      MIN(TIMESTAMP(Transaction_Datetime)) min_ts,
      MAX(TIMESTAMP(Transaction_Datetime)) max_ts
    FROM `project.dataset.table`
  ), UNNEST(GENERATE_TIMESTAMP_ARRAY(
    TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(min_ts, HOUR),
    TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(max_ts, HOUR),
    INTERVAL 1 HOUR)) hour
), locations AS (
  SELECT Source AS location FROM `project.dataset.table`
  UNION DISTINCT 
  SELECT Destination FROM `project.dataset.table`
), product_groups AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT Product_Group FROM `project.dataset.table`
), temp AS (
  SELECT 
    EXTRACT(HOUR FROM Transaction_Datetime) hour,
    DATE(Transaction_Datetime) day,
    Source, Destination, Product_ID, Product_Group
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
)
SELECT hour, day, location, product_group,
  SUM(delta) OVER(PARTITION BY location, product_group ORDER BY hour, day) amount
FROM (
  SELECT 
    hours.hour, hours.day, location, product_groups.product_group,
    SUM(CASE location 
      WHEN Source THEN -1
      WHEN Destination THEN 1
      ELSE 0
    END) delta 
  FROM locations, hours, product_groups
  LEFT JOIN temp t
  ON t.hour = hours.hour
  AND t.day = hours.day
  AND t.product_group = product_groups.product_group
  AND location IN (Source, Destination)
  GROUP BY hours.hour, hours.day, location, Product_Group
)
WHERE LOWER(location) LIKE 'shelf%' 
-- ORDER BY hour, day, location
```

Comment: Thanks Mikhail! I will test this also!

Comment: @Cristian - sure. consider also voting up the answer if it was helpful

Comment: This gives total different result from the first example. The "CASE" is expecting a source or destination but theres no source or destination in "locations" table. As you may suspect I'm a sql noob.

Comment: are you sure you properly tested query in my answer? as you are sql noob - I suspect you did it wrong! see update in the answer